# Flutter how to add color to Data Column like in image attached, without importing any packages

Tags: flutter, dart, datatable

How to add background color to Container for DataColumn, same as in image attached.

[image]

When I try this:

```
  DataTable(
        columnSpacing: 40,
        columns: [
          DataColumn(label: Flexible(child: Container(color: MyColor.lightGray, child:Text('label', style: SBTextStyle.medium(bold: true))))),
          DataColumn(label: Flexible(child: Container(color: MyColor.lightGray, child:Text('category', style: SBTextStyle.medium(bold: true))))),
          DataColumn(label: Flexible(child: Container(color: MyColor.lightGray, child:Text('items', style: SBTextStyle.medium(bold: true))))),
          DataColumn(label: Flexible(child: Container(color: MyColor.lightGray, child:Text('', style: SBTextStyle.medium(bold: true))))),
        ],       
      ),
```

It looks like this, there a lot of empty space between columns. How to add color to headers?

[image]

Comment: Please provide more of your code.

Comment: There is not so much code to show I only care about Data columns, which are in DataTable widget

Comment: There might be a better way to do this than what you're thinking of now and providing more couldn't hurt. I haven't personally used these widgets so I don't have anything coming to mind from what was provided.

Comment: Currently we can't add colors to headers using this widget. I'd suggest to use `Table` widget instead, which has `decoration` property inside `TableRow` with which you can add color to entire row.

Answer (score 0):

Try this way!

```
Container(color:Colors.blue, child: DataColumn(label: Flexible(child: Container(color: MyColor.lightGray, child:Text('label', style: SBTextStyle.medium(bold: true)))))),
```

Comment: Good point! But if I put whole DataTable in containers all rows will have background, I just want columns. there are no way that just DataColumn be in Container

Comment: I think not because DataColumn seems not be having any color parameter that why